# 'Object doesn't support this property or method' shown for jQuery.noconflict()

Tags: internet-explorer-8, mootools, onload, jquery

My jsp loads Mootools, Jquery and then my Javascript file in the same order.
In IE8, on first load, it throws error "Object doesn't support this property or method" and the JS doesn't work at all.

I load the files in JSP as:

```
new Asset.javascript('/js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js', {id: 'jQuery'});
new Asset.javascript('/js/MyScript.js', {id: 'CWScript'});
```

The MyScript.js looks as:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
...
```

It works fine in FF, IE6, Chrome and Safari but breaks at Line 1 Char 1 in IE8

Comment: Try giving it a different `id`. IE makes `id` properties of the `window` object IIRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Mootools, but for me it looks like simple race condition (assuming that Assets are loaded asynchronously and executed without any specified order). Try to load `MyScript.js` in `onLoad` callback of jQuery loading Asset.

And, keep in mind - if you are using `jQuery.noConfilct` I strongly suggest to use this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    //here you have local to jQuery under $ variable
});
```